# Hibernate slqjdbc4 column with spaces

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008

I need to map in Java with hibernate a table in sqlserver that has spaces in the  column names.
I use `Sqlserver 2008` `jre7` `com.microsoft.sqlserver.sqljdbc4` with `Hibernate 3.3.2`
I found a lot of similar questions in different forums but none of the solutions I read worked.

I tried using the backtick

```
    <property name="nameSpaces" type="string" >
        <column name="`Name with spaces`"  not-null="false" />
    </property>
```

this is the error

```
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '`'.
```

I also tried to use the [] brakets but hibernate converted it in ` again.

```
        <column name="[Name with spaces]"  not-null="false" />

      com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '`'.
```

Finally I also tried both of them

```
        <column name="`[Name with spaces]`"  not-null="false" />
```

or

without success.

Can someone help me? Is there any hibernate configuration I can change to work with these column names.

Thanks

Comment: Why you want a space in the column name in first place? use snake_case

Comment: I do not want spaces, unfortunately I didn't design database I was asked to do not change the columns name.

Comment: My friend, I'm annotation fan. I try it and it works so smooth with annotations.
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"test_table\"")
public class TestModel {@Id @Column(name="\"test id\"")
 private int id;

 public TestModel() {
 }

}

Answer (score 0):

The answer (by BilalDja) is hidden above in a comment. I found his answer helpful so I thought I would add the answer here for others with the same problem.

This issue is hard to debug, I had to dig really deep into the hibernate and jdbc code to finally find the "real" SQL statement that is created to get data from the database. I then copied its value and ran it manually on my SQL Server database. Straight away the syntax error was obvious and sure enough it was cause by a space in a column name.

To fix this I just escaped the double quotes around the problematic column name as explained in BilalDja's comments and expanded slightly here...

```
@Column(name = "\"Column name\"")
private String variableColumnWillMapTo;
```

That's it, problem solved, no more syntax error.